# Applying grouping to values greater than average

Tags: matlab

I have a vector where I want to group based on the rolling average of the values in my vector.  If the values are greater than average than I place them in group 1, if they are less they go in group 2.

What function can be used to give a group number to each to value within my vector based on whether or not its value is greater than the current average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a function to assign "labels" to array entries.

Assuming v is your input vector, an easy approach would be to simply do:

```
v(v>mean(v)) %Group 1
v(v<mean(v)) %Group 2
```

If you intend on doing more with it of course, you could do the following:

```
avg = mean(v);
flag = zeros(size(v));
for i=1:numel(v)
   if(v(i)>avg)
      flag(i) = 1;
   else
      flag(i) = 2;
   end
end
```

`flag` would contain your requisite grouping. Now if you want the elements of `v` in group `1`, you can simply use:

```
v(flag==1)
```

If you want a rolling average though, it depends on how you compute it, but the same basic method should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple function that will do that.  You'll need something like this:

```
N = length(vec);
[lo_group hi_group] = deal( NaN(ceil(N/2),1) );
[sum lo_ct hi_ct] = deal(0);
for i=1:N
   v = vec(i);
   sum = sum + v;
   avg = sum/i;
   if v>avg
      hi_ct = hi_ct + 1;
      hi_group(hi_ct) = v;
   else
      lo_ct = lo_ct + 1;
      lo_group(lo_ct) = v;
   end
end
```